# Why do the clone_flags of do_fork() have different naming conventions?

Tags: kernel, history

Recently I am studying Linux Kernel Programming and I found some weird things. The `clone_flags` of `do_fork()` are listed in `<uapi/linux/sched.h>`, but I found they have different naming conventions in term of semantic.

Roughly the `clone_flags` can be divided into following categories:

1. `CLONE_VM`, `CLONE_FS`, `CLONE_FILES`, ...: `CLONE_ABC` meaning the parent process and child process **share** resource ABC
2. `CLONE_NEWNS`, `CLONE_NEWIPC`, `CLONE_NEWUSER`, ...: `CLONE_NEWABC` meaning **create new** ABC for child process
3. `CLONE_SETTLS`: this is the only one that **create new** TLS for child process
4. `CLONE_IO`: this is the only one that **clone** IO context for child process
5. some other stuff that is not closely related to resource sharing scheme

I think these flags are quite different in naming convention. As why can't we drop `NEW` in the second category and just merge them into the first category. And `CLONE_IO` is completely the opposite of the first category.

Is there any historical reason for such a weird(I think) situation? Or is there any explanation for how the naming convention works?

Comment: Wild guess: different people added them at different times.

Answer (score 0):

> As why can't we drop NEW in the second category and just merge them into the first category.

Because you can tell what's done at first glance. If flag contains `NEW` - we are creating resource.
If we are working with `TID` - flag contains `TID` ( `CLONE_PARENT_SETTID`, `CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID`, `CLONE_CHILD_SETTID` ).
I don't find this naming convention weird.

Comment: But why not merge category 1 into 2 then? And how to explain CLONE_IO?

Comment: I fail to imagine, how you can merge two groups in one and not harm readability. Can you provide your variant ( edit question )? About `CLONE_IO` - yes, it looks like a stand-alone option. I think there can be applied @muru's explanation.